# UIViewAnimation works in a single view controller but not when it is segued into from another view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, swift, uiviewanimation

I have an animation function that works perfectly fine when there is only a single View Controller. When it runs, the block on the left hand side moves to the right hand side. The code for the animation is below.

```
let timerSquare = UIView()

func timerRectangle(){

timerSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
timerSquare.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 450, width: 50, height: 20)
self.view.addSubview(timerSquare)
UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations:
{
self.timerSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
self.timerSquare.frame = CGRect(x: 270, y: 450, width: 50, height: 20)
}, completition: nil)
}
```

However the problem happens when I create a view controller with a simple button that segues into the view controller with the animation code. Once it segues into the code the animation doesnt run and it displays the block in its finish position as though the animation had already completed running.

The View controller has no other code other than the animation code and Ive placed the animation function in numerous parts of the view controller including the "ViewDidLoad" section and Im unsure why it doesnt run the animation from the initial position. It works perfectly fine on its own and the only thing different is creating a button seguing into the code so its puzzling me. Any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution to the problem. I needed to add the subview in viewDidLoad and then start the animation in viewDidAppear so it would begin as soon as the View appeared. Hope this helped anyone else out there having the same problem

Comment: I see you found a solution, but I wanted to comment if it may help. The UIViewAnimation works with views within a view controller, not between view controllers. If you want a custom transition in your segue, look into subclassing UIStoryboardSegue and overriding the `perform` method.